# Physical constraints on fluid models based on Shannon entropy/information

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Is it possible to use the idea of entropy to constrain mathematical objects meant to describe physical fluid motion
which is virtually incompressible and virtually without friction.
More precisely partitioning space into small regions
and allowing the fluid to move for a small interval of time
the transport of fluid is described by a matrix which records how much fluid moves from the its region to the $j $th region.
The Shannon entropy/information of this matrix is defined. Are these entropies constrained by some physical principle.

Comment: Hmmm... not the worst idea I have seen today. You could definitely use ad-hoc flow rules for incompressibility (which automatically enforces motion on closed curves and that greatly constrains the system on all scales in my opinion) and, most likely some version of detailed balance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance should come into play, but that's more of a gut feeling. It would be interesting to see if one could get such a model to show phase transitions to fully developed turbulence.